# Hibernate JUnit method add always return 0 instead last added id

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, junit4

I wanna to test that I can insert correct data to db. For that I use mock for my service layer. I know that method for which I write test work correct. For all methods which select data I get rignt results. But when I try to insert data and return last inserted record id I get 0.

```
public class SeasonServiceImplTest extends BaseServiceTest {

    private static final String SEASON_NAME = "2012-2013";

    private SeasonServiceImpl seasonService;
    private SeasonDao seasonDao;
    private LanguageDao languageDao;

    public SeasonServiceImplTest() {
    }

    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        seasonService = createService(SeasonServiceImpl.class);

        seasonDao = mock(SeasonDao.class);
        when(getDap().getDao(SeasonDao.class)).thenReturn(seasonDao);

        languageDao = mock(LanguageDao.class);
        when(getDap().getDao(LanguageDao.class)).thenReturn(languageDao);
    }

    private SeasonBean createSeasonBean(){
        SeasonBean seasonBean = new SeasonBean();
        Long langId = 1L;
        seasonBean.setId(langId);
        seasonBean.setSeason(SEASON_NAME);
        Map<Long, String> seasonNames = new HashMap<>();
        seasonNames.put(langId, SEASON_NAME);
        seasonBean.setSeasons(seasonNames);
        seasonBean.setBeach(true);
        return seasonBean;
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddSeason() throws TechnicalException, LogicalException {
        Long idAddedSeason = seasonService.addSeason(createSeasonBean());
        SeasonBean selectedSeasonBean = seasonService.getSeasonById(idAddedSeason);
        assertNotNull("Season wasn't added", selectedSeasonBean);
    }
}
```

And insert in DAO

```
//addSeason in DAO layer
@Override
    public Long insert(T entity) {
        getSession().save(entity);
        return (Long) getSession().getIdentifier(entity);
    }
```

Why can be last inserted record id equls 0?

Comment: There's not enough information to help. What do you mock exactly? How's `seasonService` intatiated? And so on...

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth I completed test class